# Why cannot redefine property?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

When I run the following code, I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot redefine property: isBoolean

Why can't I redefine those properties?

```js
function isBoolean() {
  var value = arguments[0];
  if (!arguments.length) {return;}
  if (value===undefined || value===null) { return false; }
  if (typeof(value) === "boolean") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function isString() {
  var value = arguments[0];
  if (!arguments.length) {return;}
  if (value===undefined || value===null) { return false; }
  if (typeof(value) === "string") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function isNumber() {
  var value = arguments[0];
  if (!arguments.length) {return;}
  if (onoff) {
    if (value === Infinity) { return Infinity; }
  }
  if (value===undefined || value===null) { return false; }
  if (typeof(value) === "number") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function isArray() {
  var value = arguments[0];
  if (!arguments.length) {return;}
  return Array.isArray(value);
}

Object.defineProperties(window, {
//  "thisType" : { enumerable: false },
  "isBoolean": { enumerable: false },
  "isString" : { enumerable: false },
  "isNumber" : { enumerable: false },
  "isArray"  : { enumerable: false },
});
```

Comment: Post all code here directly as text. Never link to code, and *certainly* never link to pictures of code.

Comment: Please post your code, not a link to a picture of it.

Comment: Please see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5):

Because a global function declaration creates a binding on the global object (the window, on browsers) whose `configurable` flag is `false`. This is covered in [GlobalDeclarationInstantiation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation), which uses [CreateGlobalVarBinding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-createglobalvarbinding) to create the binding for the function, passing `false` as the `D` flag, which is used for the `configurable` flag. (It's in Step 18.a, function names are part of the `declaredVarNames`, which come from `varDeclarations`, which are retrieved via [VarScopedDeclarations](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-block-static-semantics-toplevelvarscopeddeclarations), which includes [HoistableDeclaration](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations)s, one of which is FunctionDeclaration.)

Since the binding isn't configurable, you can't change its `enumerable` flag from `true` to `false`.

Comment: But why? Why cant we delete functions in the global object, but override them to undefined?

Comment: @Jonasw: You'd have to ask Brendan Eich, but I think it's because function declarations are effectively the same as `var` declarations, except of course they have their value right away, and it didn't make sense (to him, way back when) that you'd change the essential properties of those. But that's speculation.

Comment: This is one of those hidden gems of an answer. So detailed, and going straight to the specs. Thanks for such a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you declare a function on the global scope, it already places it on the `window` object *with the configurable flag equal to false*. One way to avoid this is to define the functions inside of another function (an IIFE works great) like so:

You also should be setting the `value` property of the `props` object inside [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties), otherwise the value defaults to `undefined` as per the docs.

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';
  function isBoolean() {
    var value = arguments[0];
    if (!arguments.length) {return;}
    if (value===undefined || value===null) { return false; }
    if (typeof(value) === "boolean") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function isString() {
    var value = arguments[0];
    if (!arguments.length) {return;}
    if (value===undefined || value===null) { return false; }
    if (typeof(value) === "string") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function isNumber() {
    var value = arguments[0];
    if (!arguments.length) {return;}
    if (onoff) {
      if (value === Infinity) { return Infinity; }
    }
    if (value===undefined || value===null) { return false; }
    if (typeof(value) === "number") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function isArray() {
    var value = arguments[0];
    if (!arguments.length) {return;}
    return Array.isArray(value);
  }

  Object.defineProperties(window, {
    "isBoolean": { enumerable: false, value: isBoolean },
    "isString" : { enumerable: false, value: isString },
    "isNumber" : { enumerable: false, value: isNumber },
    "isArray"  : { enumerable: false, value: isArray },
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you put the `ecmascript-6` tag in your question, may I suggest you to use `let` or `const` with function expressions? Contrary to a function statement/declaration (which roughly behaves like `var`), global variables/constants declared with `let`/`const` do not become properties of the global object (here `window`).

```js
const isBoolean = function () {
  var value = arguments[0];
  if (!arguments.length) {return;}
  if (value===undefined || value===null) { return false; }
  if (typeof(value) === "boolean") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

const isString = function () {
  var value = arguments[0];
  if (!arguments.length) {return;}
  if (value===undefined || value===null) { return false; }
  if (typeof(value) === "string") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

const isNumber = function () {
  var value = arguments[0];
  if (!arguments.length) {return;}
  if (onoff) {
    if (value === Infinity) { return Infinity; }
  }
  if (value===undefined || value===null) { return false; }
  if (typeof(value) === "number") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

const isArray = function () {
  var value = arguments[0];
  if (!arguments.length) {return;}
  return Array.isArray(value);
};

console.log('"window" properties before "defineProperties":');
console.log('isBoolean: ' + ("isBoolean" in window));
console.log('isString: ' + ("isString" in window));
console.log('isNumber: ' + ("isNumber" in window));
console.log('isArray: ' + ("isArray" in window));

Object.defineProperties(window, {
  "isBoolean": { enumerable: false },
  "isString" : { enumerable: false },
  "isNumber" : { enumerable: false },
  "isArray"  : { enumerable: false },
});

console.log('"window" properties after "defineProperties":');
console.log('isBoolean: ' + ("isBoolean" in window));
console.log('isString: ' + ("isString" in window));
console.log('isNumber: ' + ("isNumber" in window));
console.log('isArray: ' + ("isArray" in window));
```