# TypeError: Cannot redefine property: ɵfac in angular

Tags: angular

```
core.js:27478 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: ɵfac
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at addDirectiveFactoryDef (core.js:27478:1)
    at compileComponent (core.js:27361:1)
    at ɵ3$1 (core.js:27674:93)
    at TypeDecorator (core.js:3758:1)
    at __decorate (tslib.es6.js:58:53)
    at Module.ENgC (collection-list-section-form.component.ts:46:48)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84:1)
    at Module.GCp2 (sub-action-file-upload.component.ts:9:42)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84:1)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
My package.json is

```
{
  "name": "frontend-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "build-production": "ng build --prod --configuration production",
    "build-staging": "ng build --prod --configuration staging",
    "build-develop": "ng build --prod --configuration develop",
    "test": "ng test --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint --ts-config tsconfig.json --tslint-config tslint.json",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular-material-components/moment-adapter": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.4",
    "@material-extended/mde": "^3.0.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngxs/storage-plugin": "^3.7.1",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^19.0.0",
    "angular-google-tag-manager": "1.4.2",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.5.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "ngx-captcha": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^8.2.0",
    "ngx-csv-parser": "0.0.7",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "13.2.0",
    "ngx-youtube-player": "^12.0.1",
    "ngxs-reset-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.6",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.4",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.7.1",
    "@schematics/angular": "^12.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~6.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.0.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: if its a fresh app and you face only this error; then remove `node_modules` folder and install again using `npm i`

Comment: did u see this subject?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052813/why-cannot-redefine-property

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
"@ngxs/storage-plugin": "^3.7.1",
"@ngxs/store": "^3.7.1",
```

so you will install ngxs latest version (you could check with npm list --depth=1
)

I have solved this problem pegging the version to 3.7.3, without ^ (I am facing the problem with 3.7.4, I still don't know the main cause, but downgrading to 3.7.3 fixed it for me).

== UPDATE

Just in case, there is a bug report realted https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/1855